# React-router-dom: How to update the props on a wrapper component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have my App component like this:

```js
const App = (props) => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <PageTheme {...some props I'd like to change on route change}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/example">
          <Example {...props} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/example/detail/:exampleId">
          <ExampleDetail {...props} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </PageTheme>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

The `PageTheme` component wrapping the `Switch` has some navigation UI, as well as some options about a page's background color, etc..  Is there a way to provide `PageTheme` some specific props for each route? Or is the best option to put a new `PageTheme` component inside of each `Route`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) and wrap `PageTheme` with it:

```
export default withRouter(PageTheme);
```

Or use `useLocation` hook if `PageTheme` is function component. Than you will have access to `location` and do your magic based on current route/url.